# Why “Daddy” in this sentence was written with a capital D?

Tags: meaning, grammar, verbs, idioms, expressions

Why is *Daddy* in this sentence written with a capital D?

> Her love letters to and from **Daddy** were in an old box, tied with ribbons and stiff, rigid-with-age leather thongs.

This sentence is from the essay named *My mother never worked* by Bonnie Smith-Yackel.

Comment: May I ask something? I presume that you already read the whole essay. Who do you think is the "Daddy" there? Is it a real person in the essay?

Comment: yes Daddy is real.Daddy is Bonnie s father

Comment: In my experience, you put capital letter when you are pertaining to a deity or God. You also put capital letter in proper nouns. Therefore, grammatically speaking, I cannot find any basis to make it "Daddy". Since it is an essay, it is in the prerogative of the writer whether to capitalize the words or not. This is only my opinion, however.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please refer to the answer in this link.

http://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20090905044418AA92kQ6

> It is correct to capitalize those terms when Mum or Dad is used
>   instead of their name. If you are writing "my mum" or "your dad", then
>   the term is not capitalized.